# Is $\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1-\frac{1}{2^{(2^i)}})$ transcendental?

Tags: nt.number-theory, pr.probability

**Motivation.** In a coin game, a player flips all their coins every turn, starting with just one coin. If the coins all land *heads* then the game stops; otherwise, the number of coins is doubled for the following turn. While the game may clearly terminate on any turn, there is in fact a positive probability that it will never terminate: this is the infinite product $$p = \prod_{i=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{(2^i)}}\right).$$

**Questions.** Do we have $p \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$? Is $p$ transcendental?

Comment: this is the [Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function) $\phi(1/2)$, see  https://oeis.org/A048651 --- I don't think it is known whether it is transcendental or not.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @CarloBeenakker, can you post this as an answer so we can close this thread?

Comment: As a funny recreational remark, with a certain combination of (poorly designed) cards, this probabilistic model actually occurred in the card game Magic: the Gathering: see https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/55075/after-how-many-iterations-can-i-shortcut-the-delina-wild-mage-pixie-guide-com.

EDIT: whoops, not quite the same, only adding one coin every iteration, not doubling them.

Comment: @SamHopkins Actually the formula given does not match the verbal description but does match (up to replacing $2$ with another constant) the numerical formula. To actually match the verbal description it should be $\prod_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(1 -\frac{1}{2^{2^i}} \right)$.

Comment: @WillSawin: Ah yes, good catch! The question should be edited then!

Comment: sage: numerical_approx(prod([1-1/(2^(2^i)) for i in range(1,20)]),digits=100)
0.7003677308791392177331090539323577352841730043538435394129646772096512610737392882895636761103029328

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can prove that the number actually described by the word problem, which is $$ \prod_{i=0}^{\infty} \left( 1- \frac{1}{2^{2^i}} \right),$$ is irrational, by a method similar to David Speyer's.

Expanding out the product, we get $$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{t_j} }{2^j}= 1+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{t_j} }{2^j} = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ 2^j} + \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{t_j} }{2^j}  = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1+ (-1)^{t_j} }{2^j} = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1+ (-1)^{t_j} }{2} \cdot 2^{1-j}  $$ where $t_j$ is the number of $1$s in the binary expansion of $j$.

Thus the binary digit in the $j-1$th place is $1$ if $t_j$ is even and $0$ if $t_j$ is odd.

Since this sequence is not periodic, the number is irrational.

Comment: In fact, this number is transcendental: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prouhet%E2%80%93Thue%E2%80%93Morse_constant

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Emil! And the link to the Thue-Morse sequence is amazing!

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen I'm a little bothered that, in your question, the verbal description and the formula don't match. Which one do you really mean? I would have assumed that the verbal description takes precedence, but if so, then it would seem that this answer by Will and Emil should be the accepted answer.

Comment: You are absolutely right Timothy, will correct my error

Answer (score 27):

This number is irrational. By [Euler's pentagonal number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem), we have
$$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-2^{-i}) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \left( 2^{-k(3k+1)/2} +2^{-k(3k-1)/2} \right).$$
This shows that the binary expansion is clearly not periodic.

I have no idea whether this number is transcendental. Your number is closely related to the value of various modular forms like the [Dedekind eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function) at $\tau = \tfrac{\log 2}{2 \pi} i$, so $q = \tfrac{1}{2}$. Chapter 27 of Transcendental numbers, by [Murty and Rath](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4939-0832-5), discusses evaluating modular forms when $\tau$ is an algebraic number, but a quick search didn't show me anything about evaluating modular forms when $q$ is algebraic.

Comment: For posterity: this answer addresses the original version of the question, which was about the infinite product $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-\frac{1}{2^i})$. As mentioned in the comments under the question, that product also has a probabilistic interpretation, where instead of doubling the number of coins each turn, we add one one.

Answer (score 9):

**Q:** Is $\prod_{i=1}^\infty(1-2^{-i})$ transcendental?
<sub>The question as posed originally by the OP.</sub>

**A:** This is the [Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function) $\phi(1/2)$, see https://oeis.org/A048651 --- I don't think it is known whether it is transcendental or not [as is the case for other instances of $\phi(q)$].